# Exceptions in high-level grouping of corountines with asyncio.gather

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am currently working on a project where I launch a couple of coroutines, which I group together with `asyncio.gather`. Then, I group all these subgroups together, once again with `asyncio.gather`.
Everything works perfectly except when an error occurs. The error is not propagated to the main program, whereas the `return_exceptions` keyword is not set to True.

Here's a way to reproduce:

```py
import asyncio

async def ok_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def error_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("crashed!")
    raise RuntimeError

async def create_coros():
    return asyncio.gather(ok_task(), error_task())

def main():
    subgroup_1 = create_coros()
    subgroup_2 = create_coros()
    subgroup_3 = create_coros()

    main_group = asyncio.gather(subgroup_1, subgroup_2, subgroup_3)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        main_group
    )
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`crashed!` correctly appears three times on the console, but no `RuntimeError` is raised.

However, if I modify the `create_coros` function with `return await asyncio.gather(ok_task(), error_task())`, the excepted behaviour occurs.

Can anyone explain why exceptions aren't propagated without the additional `await` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes to make your code work as expected. On the other hand if I were you I would try to go along with only one `gather` and accumulate all coroutines in that one `gather`.

```py
import asyncio


async def ok_task():
    """Not infinite loop  now"""
    n = 10
    while n:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        n -= 1
    return 100  # let's return some number


async def error_task():
    """It always make problems"""
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("crashed!")
    raise RuntimeError("NOooo!!!")


async def create_coros():
    """Accumulate tasks here"""
    # return_exceptions=True - since we expect errors
    # should return some Coroutine which return result of 
    # await asyncio.gather(ok_task(), error_task(), return_exceptions=True)
    # await is used to return appropriate datatype for gather function
    # which expect coroutines as args
    return await asyncio.gather(ok_task(), error_task(), return_exceptions=True)


async def amain():
    # create several groups of coroutines
    subgroup_1 = create_coros()
    subgroup_2 = create_coros()
    subgroup_3 = create_coros()

    # gather expect coroutines 
    r = await asyncio.gather(subgroup_1, subgroup_2, subgroup_3)
    print(f"Final Result: {r}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think you got my question. First, I don't want to use `return_exceptions=True` as I actually want the error to be raised.
Also, my question is why we need to use the `await` in the `create_coros` function, as the error is not raised without it.

Comment: @RobBlanchard if you need the whole program to stop due to error, remove `return_exceptions=True`, it is '=False' by default. I use await in `create_coros` to return appropriate for `gather` type - `Coroutine`, if you keep your code as it is, you returns `<class 'asyncio.tasks._GatheringFuture'>`, it is incorrect way to use `gather`.

Comment: Ok thanks, the inappropriate type answers my question, although I don't understand why most of the code works without the await. Would you mind changing your answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: @RobBlanchard do you want me to only remove `return_exceptions=True` or any other changes?

Comment: Just point out that the use of `await` is required in order to return a Coroutine

Comment: @RobBlanchard ok, I added some comments to explain `await` in that case